# How to set base for scientific notation on x-axis in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots

When using a log scale for the x-axis in a scatter plot I get weird powers as xticks, e.g. 10^-3.4.

I want to change this so that I have standard scientific notation, that is for example 1.3x10^-3.

How can I do that? All the methods that I tried work only for the y-axis and not the x-axis.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{filecontents}{table3.csv}
    learning_rate dropout val_accuracy
    0.001303378998921129 0.25059722463372325 0.8734264969825745
    0.000503378998921129 0.46059722463372325 0.9034264969825745

\end{filecontents}
    

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmode=log,
        scaled y ticks=base 10:-2,  % this doesn't really make sense here, but I wanted to show that it works forr the y axis and not x axis
        scaled x ticks=base 10:-2,
        ]
        \addplot+[
            only marks,
            scatter,
            point meta={\thisrow{val_accuracy}},
            ]
        table{table3.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Plot with weird scientific notation on x-axis]

Comment: Welcome. // At least for debugging I’d put a second data point into your file, even an artificial one. // Did you check e.g. ch. 82.2.4 in the pgf manual?

Comment: I just read "82.2.4 Scaling: The General Mechanism" from the pgf manual found here https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf, but I didn't find anything about the scientific notations, exponents etc, I only found information about scaling axis